# TypeError: "class" object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, random, range, list-comprehension

I am trying to build an UNO simulation in python. I have been creating some objects, and once I generated the decks and the players, I wanted to deal the cards out to players. However I get this error with my code:

```
TypeError: 'card' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\jense\VSCODE\Games\Cards.py in <module>
----> 1 uno(5).players[2]

c:\Users\jense\VSCODE\Games\Cards.py in __init__(self, num_players)
     68 
     69         # deal cards
---> 70         drawn_cards, self.game_deck = [[self.deal(game_deck)] for i in range((len(self.players)))]
     71 
     72         # zip the drawn cards to each player object

c:\Users\jense\VSCODE\Games\Cards.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     68 
     69         # deal cards
---> 70         drawn_cards, self.game_deck = [[self.deal(game_deck)] for i in range((len(self.players)))]
     71 
     72         # zip the drawn cards to each player object

c:\Users\jense\VSCODE\Games\Cards.py in deal(self, deck_of_cards)
     75     def deal(self, deck_of_cards):
     76         # draw 7 cards
---> 77         player_cards = [[deck_of_cards.pop(random.choice(deck_of_cards))] for i in range(7)]
     78         return player_cards, deck_of_cards
     79 

c:\Users\jense\VSCODE\Games\Cards.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     75     def deal(self, deck_of_cards):
     76         # draw 7 cards
---> 77         player_cards = [[deck_of_cards.pop(random.choice(deck_of_cards))] for i in range(7)]
     78         return player_cards, deck_of_cards
     79 

TypeError: 'card' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Here is all of the code that I have so far:

I suspect the problem has to do with my "deal" function, but I dont really understand the error. In this example I want to pop a card from the list of cards in game deck, 7 times, for 5 players, deleting the randomly selected cards from the deck, and then assign the cards to a player.

```
import random

class card():

    def __init__(self, value, color, wild):

        '''
        An UNO deck consists of 108 cards, of which there are 76 Number cards,
        24 Action cards and 8 Wild cards. UNO cards have four color "suits", 
        which are red, yellow, blue and green.
        '''

        card_nums = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
        card_colors = ['red','blue','green','yellow']
        spec_cards = ['draw2','reverse','skip']
        wild_cards = ['wild','wild_draw_4']

        if wild == False:
            self.value = card_nums[value]
            self.color = card_colors[color]
        elif wild == 'special':
            self.value = spec_cards[value]
            self.color = card_colors[color]
        elif wild == True:
            self.value = wild_cards[value]
            self.color = None

class deck():

    def __init__(self):
        self.number_cards = self.get_num_cards()
        self.special_cards = self.get_special_cards()
        self.wild_cards = self.get_wild_cards()
        self.cards = self.number_cards + self.special_cards + self.wild_cards
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def get_num_cards(self):
        # only one zero per color
        with_zeroes = [card(i,j,False) for i in range(10) for j in range(4)]
        no_zeroes = [card(i,j,False) for i in range(1,10) for j in range(4)]
        return no_zeroes + with_zeroes

    def get_wild_cards(self):
        wild_draw4s = [card(i,None,True) for i in range(2) for x in range(2)]
        wilds = [card(i,None,True) for i in range(2) for x in range(2)]
        return wilds + wild_draw4s

    def get_special_cards(self):
        return [card(i,j,'special') for i in range(3) for j in range(4) for x in range(2)]

class player():

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.wins = 0
        self.player_cards = []
        self.name = name
        
class uno():

    def __init__(self, num_players):

        # generate deck of cards
        game_deck = deck().cards

        # generate players with 7 cards each
        self.players = [player('player' + str(i)) for i in range(num_players)]

        # deal cards
        drawn_cards, self.game_deck = [self.deal(game_deck) for i in range(num_players)]
        
        # zip the drawn cards to each player object
        players = zip(drawn_cards, self.players)

    def deal(self, deck_of_cards):
        # draw 7 cards
        player_cards = [deck_of_cards.pop(random.choice(deck_of_cards)) for i in range(7)]
        return player_cards, deck_of_cards
```

Comment: Seems pretty clear, `random.choice` returns a random card from the list but `pop` expects the *integer index*. Use `random.randint(0, len(deck_of_cards) - 1)` don't confuse the position of the thing in a list of things with the thing itself.

Comment: Please extract a [mcve] and include its output in the question as well.

Comment: Why don't you `.shuffle()` the deck, then just iterate through the shuffled deck to deal?